# Not able to insert the customer SeName in UrlRecord Table in nopcommerce

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90

Currently i am stucked in one point that when the customer completes its registration process what i want to do is Create a SeName from customers email address and store it in UrlRecord Table so that i can enable navigation to customers profile page. Below is the code that i had tried till now.

```
string CustomerSeName = "";
var CustomerModel=_customerService.GetCustomerById(_workContext.CurrentCustomer.Id);
if (CustomerModel != null)
{
       CustomerSeName = customer.ValidateSeName(CustomerSeName, CustomerModel.Email, true);
       _urlRecordService.SaveSlug(CustomerModel, CustomerSeName, 0);
}
```

in above code i am getting all the value in CustomerModel and CustomerSeName but when it executes SaveSlug() method it throws an Object reference not set error. I dont know which value  it missing.Please help me out if someone knows the solution. Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Did you extend Customer entity with ISlugSupported? Because i cannot compile your code in nopCommerce 3.9

Comment: yes i already done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and couldn't compile.

After adding **ISlugSupported** to Customer entity and using this code all worked

```
private void GenerateCurrentCustomerSlug()
{
    var slug = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.ValidateSeName(seName: "", name: _workContext.CurrentCustomer.Email, ensureNotEmpty: true);
    _urlRecordService.SaveSlug(_workContext.CurrentCustomer, slug, languageId: 0);
}
```

The above code also works if there is no email set for current customer.

Comment: yes i already resolved the problem. What i did is an CustomerRegistered Event is raised when a customer is successfully registered. So i created a new event handler which catches that event and in that handler i successfully inserted the Slug name in UrlRecord Table. But i would like to know that does some parameter is required for inserting an Slug in UrlRecord table ?

Comment: It is because of the type constraint on the SaveSlug method.

Comment: Ha yes @Raphael, may be you are right because i had to pass the Customer type model in SaveSlug() method in Event handler.